# What is the best way to utilize nth-child in CSS to make it cleaner?

Tags: css

I wrote this code out but it is very messy and long. I was wondering if there is a better way to use the nth-child in CSS? Or anytime you use nth-child it is always going to be messy and tedious?

Is there a better way to go about what I am doing using CSS? I am not trying to use and javascript. Thanks!

Here is the HTML:

```
<table class="agenda">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>August 4</th>
      <th>August 5</th>
      <th>August 6</th>
      <th>August 7</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Day 1 Morning</td>
      <td>Day 2 Morning</td>
      <td>Day 3 Morning</td>
      <td>Day 4 Morning</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Day 1 Afternoon</td>
      <td>Day 2 Afternoon</td>
      <td>Day 3 Afternoon</td>
      <td>Day 4 Afternoon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Day 1 Evening</td>
      <td>Day 2 Evening</td>
      <td>Day 3 Evening</td>
      <td>Day 4 Evening</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
table.agenda {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table.agenda td,
table.agenda th {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

table.agenda td {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  background-color: rgb(193, 212, 174);
  color: black;
}

th:nth-child(1) {
  background: rgb(16, 69, 150);
  color: white;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgb(16, 169, 150);
  color: white;
}

th:nth-child(3) {
  background: rgb(200, 190, 150);
  color: white;
}

th:nth-child(4) {
  background: rgb(16, 19, 75);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
  background: rgb(16, 20, 50);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) {
  background: rgb(16, 69, 150);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) {
  background: rgb(16, 20, 50);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgb(16, 200, 50);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgb(16, 169, 150);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) {
  background: rgb(16, 200, 50);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) {
  background: rgb(116, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) {
  background: rgb(200, 190, 150);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(3) {
  background: rgb(116, 50, 50);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4) {
  background: rgb(116, 50, 200);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4) {
  background: rgb(16, 19, 75);
  color: white;
}

table.agenda tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(4) {
  background: rgb(116, 50, 200);
  color: white;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wyh11L66/1/)

Comment: You can do some math with them:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: I saw your project on fiddle . you have different color variations for th and tr so you did well on use of nth child other way you can defile color and give classes to each element.

Comment: I did find a way to reduce some lines (and feel dumb for not doing this at first). Instead of having multiple:  `tr:nth-child(1,2,3, etc.) td:nth-child(n);`
Use even and odd:  
    `tr:nth-child(odd,even) td:nth-child(n);`